# при нажатии на любое место в главном меня начинается игра unity!

Tags: unity3d-android, unity3d

В юнити все хорошо нажимаю на кнопки заходит куда надо но кода я портировал под андроид и нажимаю на кнопку запускается игра а не то что я хотел допустим магазин как исправить буду благодарен за помощь!!!!!!

C#

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    private CubePos nowCube = new CubePos(0, 1, 0);
    public float cubeChangePlaceSpeed = 0.5f;
    public Transform cubeToPlace;
    public float camMoveToYposition, camMoveSpeed = 2f;



    public Text scoreTxt;

    public GameObject[] cubesToCreate;

    public GameObject allCubes, vfx;
    public GameObject[] canvasStartPage;
    private Rigidbody allCubesRb;

    public Color[] bgColors;
    private Color toCameraColor;

    private bool IsLose, firstCube;


    private List<Vector3> allCubesPositions = new List<Vector3> {
        new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        new Vector3(1, 0, 0),
        new Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
        new Vector3(0, 1, 0),
        new Vector3(0, 0, 1),
        new Vector3(0, 0, -1),
        new Vector3(1, 0, 1),
        new Vector3(-1, 0, -1),
        new Vector3(-1, 0, 1),
        new Vector3(1, 0, -1),
    };
    private int prevCountMaxHorizontal;
    private Transform mainCam;
    private Coroutine showCubePlace;

    private List<GameObject> posibleCubesToCreate = new List<GameObject>();


    private void Start() {

        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") < 3)
            posibleCubesToCreate.Add(cubesToCreate[0]);
        else if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") < 5)
            AddPosibleCubes(2);
        else if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") < 10)
            AddPosibleCubes(3);
        else if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") < 15)
            AddPosibleCubes(4);
        else if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") < 20)
            AddPosibleCubes(5);
        else if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") < 30)
            AddPosibleCubes(6);
        else if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") < 40)
            AddPosibleCubes(7);
        else if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") < 50)
            AddPosibleCubes(8);
        else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") < 100)
            AddPosibleCubes(9);
        else
            AddPosibleCubes(10);
        



        scoreTxt.text = "<size=35><color=#FA625C>Best : </color></size> " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") + "\n<size=30>NOW : </size> 0";

        toCameraColor = Camera.main.backgroundColor;

        mainCam = Camera.main.transform;

        camMoveToYposition = 5.9f + nowCube.y - 1f;

        allCubesRb = allCubes.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        showCubePlace = StartCoroutine(ShowCubePlace());
    }

    private void Update() {
        if((Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.touchCount > 0) && cubeToPlace != null && allCubes != null && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) {
            
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase != TouchPhase.Began)
                return;
#endif

            

            if(!firstCube) {
                firstCube = true;
                foreach(GameObject obj in canvasStartPage)
                    Destroy(obj);
            }

            GameObject createCube = null;
            if(posibleCubesToCreate.Count == 1)
                createCube = posibleCubesToCreate[0];
            else
                createCube = posibleCubesToCreate[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, posibleCubesToCreate.Count)];

            GameObject newCube = Instantiate(
                createCube,
                cubeToPlace.position,
                Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

            newCube.transform.SetParent(allCubes.transform);
            nowCube.setVector(cubeToPlace.position);
            allCubesPositions.Add(nowCube.getVector3());

            if(PlayerPrefs.GetString("music") != "No")
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

            GameObject newVfx = Instantiate(vfx, cubeToPlace.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(newVfx, 1.5f);


            allCubesRb.isKinematic = true;
            allCubesRb.isKinematic = false;


            SpawnPositions();
            MoveCameraChangeBg();
            
        }

        if(!IsLose && allCubesRb.velocity.magnitude > 0.1f) {
            Destroy(cubeToPlace.gameObject);
            IsLose = true;
            StopCoroutine(showCubePlace);
        }
        
        mainCam.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(mainCam.localPosition, 
            new Vector3(mainCam.localPosition.x, camMoveToYposition, mainCam.localPosition.z), 
            camMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Camera.main.backgroundColor != toCameraColor){
            Camera.main.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(Camera.main.backgroundColor, toCameraColor, Time.deltaTime / 1.5f);
        }
    }
    


    IEnumerator ShowCubePlace() {
        while(true) {
            SpawnPositions();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(cubeChangePlaceSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void SpawnPositions() {
        List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
        if(IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x + 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z))
        &&  nowCube.x + 1 != cubeToPlace.position.x)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x + 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z));
        
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x - 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z))
        &&  nowCube.x - 1 != cubeToPlace.position.x)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x - 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z));
        
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y + 1, nowCube.z))
        &&  nowCube.y + 1 != cubeToPlace.position.y)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y + 1, nowCube.z));
        
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y - 1, nowCube.z))
        &&  nowCube.y - 1 != cubeToPlace.position.y)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y - 1, nowCube.z));
        
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z + 1))
        &&  nowCube.z + 1 != cubeToPlace.position.z)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z + 1));
        
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z - 1))
        &&  nowCube.z - 1 != cubeToPlace.position.z)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z - 1));
        
        
        if(positions.Count > 1)
            cubeToPlace.position = positions[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, positions.Count)];
        else if(positions.Count == 0)
            IsLose = true;
        else
            cubeToPlace.position = positions[0];
        
    }

    private bool IsPositionEmpty(Vector3 targetPos) {
        if(targetPos.y == 0)
            return false;
        

        foreach (Vector3 pos in allCubesPositions) {
            if(pos.x == targetPos.x && pos.y == targetPos.y && pos.z == targetPos.z)
                return false;
            
        }
        return true;
    }


    private void MoveCameraChangeBg() {
        int maxX = 0, maxY = 0, maxZ = 0, maxHor;

        foreach(Vector3 pos in allCubesPositions){
            if(Mathf.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(pos.x)) > maxX)
                maxX = Convert.ToInt32(pos.x);

            if(Mathf.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(pos.y)) > maxY)
                maxY = Convert.ToInt32(pos.y);

            if(Mathf.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(pos.z)) > maxZ)
                maxZ = Convert.ToInt32(pos.z);
        }

        maxY--;

        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") < maxY) 
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", maxY);

        
        
        scoreTxt.text = "<size=35><color=#FA625C>Best : </color></size> " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score") + "\n<size=30>NOW : </size> " + maxY;
        

        camMoveToYposition = 5.9f + nowCube.y - 1f;

        maxHor = maxX > maxZ ? maxX : maxZ;
        if(maxHor % 3 == 0 && prevCountMaxHorizontal != maxHor) {
            mainCam.localPosition -= new Vector3(0, 0, 2.5f);
            prevCountMaxHorizontal = maxHor;
        }

        if(maxY >= 20) {
            toCameraColor = bgColors[6];
        } else if(maxY >= 15) {
            toCameraColor = bgColors[5];
        } else if(maxY >= 11) {
            toCameraColor = bgColors[4];
        } else if(maxY >= 9) {
            toCameraColor = bgColors[3];
        } else if(maxY >= 7) {
            toCameraColor = bgColors[2];
        } else if(maxY >= 5) {
            toCameraColor = bgColors[1];
        } else if(maxY >= 3) {
            toCameraColor = bgColors[0];
        }

    }

    private void AddPosibleCubes(int till) {
        for (int i = 0; i < till; i ++){
            posibleCubesToCreate.Add(cubesToCreate[i]);
        }
    }

}


        


struct CubePos {
    public int x, y, z;

    public CubePos(int x, int y, int z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public Vector3 getVector3() {
        return new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

    public void setVector(Vector3 pos) {
        x = Convert.ToInt32(pos.x);
        y = Convert.ToInt32(pos.y);
        z = Convert.ToInt32(pos.z);
    }

}
```

Comment: `CubePos`...? а [Vector3Int](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3Int.html) для кого придумали?

Comment: как говорится, платят за количество строк, а не их качество

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с такой проблемой, вероятно целю Raycast-а становится кнопка запуска игры.

- проверь параметр "Raycast Target" у UI элементов на кнопках
- проверь настройки у компонента "Graphic Raycaster" (обычно на
  Canvas-е находится)